# Dynamic update in SQL based on previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, azure-sql-database, window-functions

I am trying to explore the dynamic update.

My actual source table is:

[image]

Expected result of the source table after update :

[image]

The query i tried :

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT key,
           Begin_POS,
           Length,
           (Begin_POS+ Length) as res
    from   tab
)
SELECT src_column_id,
       Length,res,
       COALESCE(Length + lag(res) OVER (ORDER BY src_column_id),1)  AS PRE_VS
from t
```

Can you assist what should be my approach like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that’s a window sum:

```
select 
    t.*,
    1 + coalesce(
        sum(length) over(
            order by key 
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ), 
        0
    ) new_begin_pos
from mytable t
```

Comment: Perfect. Hope I have to use this as the temp table in my update query to get the end result?

Comment: There is no temporary table in your question, @Madan .

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SUM()` window function like this:

```
select
  [key],
  sum(length) over (order by [key]) - length + begin_pos begin_pos,
  length
from tab
```

If you want to update the table:

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(length) over (order by [key]) - length + begin_pos new_begin_pos
  from tab
)
update cte 
set begin_pos = new_begin_pos
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6315736bd4b2fd19eeaed0c762b1c050).
Results:

```
> key | begin_pos | length
> --: | --------: | -----:
>   1 |         1 |      1
>   2 |         2 |      9
>   3 |        11 |      3
>   4 |        14 |      7
>   5 |        21 |      3
>   6 |        24 |      6
>   7 |        30 |     16
```